# locating 1st 2nd largest number and their position in an array using bubble sort in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

**Write a program which reads 5 numbers into an array and prints the largest number and 2nd largest number and their postion in that array.**

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
public class bubble sort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i,j,temp;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        int array[]=new int [5];
        for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            out.println("please input an integer");
            array[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<array.length;j++)
            {
                if(array[i]>array[j])
                {
                    temp=array[i];
                    array[i]=array[j];
                    array[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
           out.print(array[0]+" is the largest number");
           out.println(array[1]+" is the 2nd largest number");

    }
}
```

**now to print their position do i have to follow another sorting method ? or is it possible with bubble sorting ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positions [0] and [1] will store the smallest numbers. Otherwise you are looking for a Reversed Bubble Sort, which is not the case of your codes.

So now, If I got your question, you can create two arrays. One for the numbers and one for their index. You sort the arrays looking for the number array, but apply the same changes for the index. So, at the end you will have both arrays sorted and can simply show the positions [4] and [3] of each one (not a good performance approach):

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
public class bubble sort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i,j,temp;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        int number_array[]=new int [5];
        int index_array[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
        for(i=0;i<number_array.length;i++)
        {
            out.println("please input an integer");
            number_array[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        for(i=0;i<number_array.length;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<number_array.length;j++)
            {
                if(number_array[i]>number_array[j])
                {
                    temp=number_array[i];
                    number_array[i]=number_array[j];
                    number_array[j]=temp;

                    temp=index_array[i];
                    index_array[i]=index_array[j];
                    index_array[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
           out.print(number_array[4]+" is the largest number with initial index "+index_array[4]);
           out.println(number_array[3]+" is the 2nd largest number with initial index "+index_array[3]);

    }
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: thanx mate that's what i was looking for .. really appriciate.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way both in terms of space complexity and time complexity is to have a hash table (aka map and dictionary) that maps values to their initial indices.